# JetBrains equivalent for Visual Studio Shift+Alt+Up/Down

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

Does JetBrains tool have an equivalent for Visual Studio/Notepad++ <kbd>Shift + Alt + Up/Down</kbd>?

Or any other simple way to move the cursor up/down one line, while extending the column selection?

Comment: Sure: `Edit | Column Selection Mode`. Also : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor

Comment: I remember having to do it the way @LazyOne mentioned which wasn't as simple as the VS way. But in a newer version of Rider with Visual Studio keybinding I can do it with the same shortcut as Visual Studio. Which version of Rider do you use Jonathan? And do you use the VS keybindings?